# Add new attribute type in OLC schema (openLdap)

Tags: attributes, debian, schema, openldap

I'm a beginner with openLDAP.

I try to add a new attribute to my LDAP olc schema.
I want to add the field "aliasMail" to my users attributes.
I create a LDIF file :

```
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.5.1.62
  NAME 'mailAlias'
  DESC 'mailAlias'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
  SINGLE-VALUE )
```

But that does not work :

```
sudo ldapmodify -x -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -W -f attributest.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
modifying entry "cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: attributeTypes: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

I also tried other syntaxes for the LDIF file like :

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: add
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.100.123 NAME 'aliasMail'
  DESC 'aliasMail' )
```

and the result is (with admin credentials) :

```
sudo ldapmodify -x -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -W -f attrbutest2.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "cn=config"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

I'm on Debian 8.

PS : sorry for my bad english.

EDIT :

I just tried another way : When I take a look on /etc/ldap/schema, I can see files .schema and .ldif. I tried to copy the format of these files on the two following files

/etc/ldap/schema/custom.schema :

```
attributetype ( 1.7.11.1.1 
    NAME 'aliasMail' 
    DESC 'aliasMail' 
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch 
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch 
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 
    SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.7.11.1.2
    NAME 'mailHomeDirectory'
    DESC 'repertoire mail'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.7.11.1.3
    NAME 'mailUidNumber'
    DESC 'mailUidNumber'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.7.11.1.4
    NAME 'mailGidNumber'
    DESC 'mailGidNumber'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.7.11.1.5
    NAME 'mailStorageDirectory'
    DESC 'mailStorageDirectory'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE )
```

/etc/ldap/schema/custom.ldif :

```
dn: cn=custom,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: custom
olcAttributeTypes: {0} ( 1.7.11.1.1 NAME 'aliasMail' DESC 'aliasMail' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.7.11.1.2 NAME 'mailHomeDirectory' DESC 'mailHomeDirectory' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.7.11.1.3 NAME 'mailUidNumber' DESC 'mailUidNumber' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.7.11.1.4 NAME 'mailGidNumber' DESC 'mailGidNumber' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.7.11.1.5 NAME 'mailStorageDirectory' DESC 'mailStorageDirectory' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

And I add it with :

```
kettbi@serveur:~$ sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com -W -f /etc/ldap/schema/custom.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "cn=custom,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

The admin DN is administrator of my LDAP domain :

```
kettbi@serveur:~$ sudo ldapsearch -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b  cn=config olcRootDN=cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com dn olcRootDN olcRootPW
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
olcRootPW: {SSHA}secret_password
```

I am realy lost...

(and sorry again for my english)

EDIT 2 :

Ok, new try :
I add this file
/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={4}custom.ldif

```
dn: cn={4}custom
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: {4}custom
olcAttributeTypes: {0} ( 1.7.11.1.1 NAME 'aliasMail' DESC 'aliasMail' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.7.11.1.2 NAME 'mailHomeDirectory' DESC 'mailHomeDirectory' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.7.11.1.3 NAME 'mailUidNumber' DESC 'mailUidNumber' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.7.11.1.4 NAME 'mailGidNumber' DESC 'mailGidNumber' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.7.11.1.5 NAME 'mailStorageDirectory' DESC 'mailStorageDirectory' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

and I set the correct permission for openldap

```
kettbi@serveur:~$ sudo chown openldap:openldap /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/cn=schema/cn={4}custom.ldif
kettbi@serveur:~$ sudo chmod 600 /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/cn=schema/cn={4}custom.ldif
```

but still not working ...
Any ideas ?

Comment: I finally found a solution but I don't think that's a "clean" solution.    
I manually add custom Attribute and objectClass on /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/cn=schema/cn={0}core.ldif. If someone have a better and cleaner solution that will be great... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Schema can be modified only from servers local root account using external authentication:

```
sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/custom.ldif
```

You can check access rights by executing:

```
sudo ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
```

The output should be similar to:

```
...
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
  ,cn=auth manage by * break
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using slapd openldap then it would be a big task to modify the config, rather i suggest you to go with opendj ldap which accepts the same ldif file you tried to upload in the slapd ldap